# How to remove multiple apps?

Tags: software-center, uninstall

I tried to remove multiple apps from the software centre GUI by <kbd>Ctrl+Select</kbd> but nothing happens. After each removal, it refreshes its screen.

I have many Thai fonts (that I could see after selecting `Show xxxx technical items`). I cannot remove each one by one. That eats up a lot of CPU and is time consuming.

Please give some alternative on how I can remove multiple packages, preferably in GUI, but commands would do too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first install synaptic, it's a software manager like software center by this command

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

or install it from software center, after installing open synaptic from main menu, enter your password, from the top bar press search and enter your keyword, then select all, right click and mark for removal, in the end click apply.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try and remove them from terminal. It seems that all the files you want to remove start with fonts-tlwg so you could do:

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-tlwg-*
```

And that does the trick.

Comment: If that doesn't remove all of the Thai fonts, remove fonts-thai-* xfonts-thai* too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI, install synaptic package manager which allows you to add/remove multiple packages.